# Structure not allowing drag/drop

Tags: control-panel, structure

Craft 2.6.2999

I have two channels that I've set to structure. In my local install I can drag/drop entries no problem. HOwever on the staging server the drag drop function doesn't work - there are no handles and the entries look like they are a regular channel.

I've tried changing the section type to channel and back to structure but no change.

Please advise

Comment: Yes that solved my problem. Thank you @BradBell

Comment: No problem, Sean.